# IEnumerable<T> thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, multithreading

I have a main thread that populates a `List<T>`.  Further I create a chain of objects that will execute on different threads, requiring access to the List.  The original list will never be written to after it's generated.  My thought was to pass the list as `IEnumerable<T>` to the objects executing on other threads, mainly for the reason of not allowing those implementing those objects to write to the list by mistake.  In other words if the original list is guaranteed not be written to, is it safe for multiple threads to use `.Where` or `foreach` on the IEnumerable?

I am not sure if the iterator in itself is thread safe if the original collection is never changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` can't be modified. So what can be non thread safe with it? (If you don't modify the actual `List<T>`).

For non thread safety you need writing and reading operations.

"Iterator in itself" is instantiated for each `foreach`.

**Edit:** I simplified my answer a bit, but @Eric Lippert added valuable comment. `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't define modifying methods, but it doesn't mean that access operators are thread safe (`GetEnumerator`, `MoveNext` and etc.) Simplest example: `GetEnumerator` implemented as this:

- Every time returns same instance of `IEnumerator`
- Resets it's position

More sophisticated example is caching.

This is interesting point, but fortunately I don't know any standard class that has not thread-safe implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I was not sure if the iterator in itself maintains internally for example in some class level variable on which item in the collection it is at a particular point.  If two threads are iterating, that internal state is compromised.  This thinking must be wrong?

Comment: You'd need to use a different Iterator for each thread, yes, but they can all be backed by the same list.

Comment: @Joseph Earl, but as Phil stated every time you do a foreach() or a where(), you're issued a new iterator to work with?  In other words this is taken care of for me.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is. I was thinking of the explicit case where you call `Iterator i = list.iterator()` and then use that - in that case you'd want to make a new iterator for each thread.

Comment: Just because an IE<T> cannot be modified *by the caller* does not guarantee that its *inner workings* are threadsafe for multiple readers! An implementation of IE<T> could contain caches or other performance-enhancing algorithms that involve writing to shared data structures, and those might not be threadsafe for multiple readers. Just because the collection is *logically* not mutated does not require that *nothing* is mutated during its enumeration.

Comment: @Eric Lippert you are totally right. I updated my answer. Do you know any standard class that has not thread-safe implementation of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @Andrey: I don't know of any, but that doesn't mean that none exist. For example, consider a dictionary that is implemented with a hash table, as you'd expect, but with a twist: when you access a key that is towards the end of the bucket list, it moves that bucket to the front of the bucket list. Such dictionaries are common in compilers because compilers frequently have the situation where the same identifier is going to occur several times close together in the code. It can be a perf win to rewrite the table internals dynamically as it is read to try to make future reads faster.

Comment: For .NET 4.5 concurrent collections such as stack and queue. 
From MSDN:
"The System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> and System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack<T> classes take a snapshot of the elements before enumerating them, to prevent mutations to the collection on another thread. The System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> class does not take a snapshot."

Answer (score 8):

Each thread that calls Where or foreach gets its own enumerator - they don't share one enumerator object for the same list. So since the List isn't being modified, and since each thread is working with its own copy of an enumerator, there should be no thread safety issues.

You can see this at work in one thread - Just create a List of 10 objects, and get two enumerators from that List. Use one enumerator to enumerate through 5 items, and use the other to enumerate through 5 items. You will see that both enumerators enumerated through only the first 5 items, and that the second one did not start where the first enumerator left off.

Comment: I think that's what was throwing me off, a new iterator is provided for each request so it's not shared.

Comment: +1 for "Each thread that calls Where or foreach gets its own enumerator" - I can't find this information anywhere. It's not clear from the docs that I could find that this is the case. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can find the proof of "Each thread that calls Where or foreach gets its own enumerator" [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs).

Comment: That completely depends on how the class implementated the `GetEnumerator` method. It's not guaranteed to return a separate instance.

Comment: @RufusL You're absolutely correct that it depends on how the class implements `GetEnumerator()`. However `List` _does_ implement it this way, and it would be _really_ strange to have a class that does it any differently. So strange, in fact, that I would consider it a bug.

Comment: Oh, right, you were only talking about a `List`. Eric Lippert had an interesting comment: *"consider a dictionary that is implemented with a hash table, as you'd expect, but with a twist: when you access a key that is towards the end of the bucket list, it moves that bucket to the front of the bucket list. Such dictionaries are common in compilers because compilers frequently have the situation where the same identifier is going to occur several times close together in the code. It can be a perf win to rewrite the table internals dynamically as it is read to try to make future reads faster."*

Comment: @RufusL Yes, even though you may have multiple enumerator objects, they will all start throwing exceptions if they notice the underlying data has changed. So don't mess around with your `List` while other threads are iterating over it.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are certain that the `List` will never be modified then it will be safe to read from multiple threads. This includes the use of the `IEnumerator` instances it provides.

This is going to be true for most collections. In fact, all collections in the BCL should be stable during enumeration. In other words, the enumerator will not modify the data structure. I can think of some obscure cases, like a splay-tree, were enumerating it *might* modify the structure. Again, none of the BCL collections do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are certain that the list will not be modified after creation, you should guarantee that by converting it to a [ReadOnlyCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). Of course if you keep the original list that the read only collection uses you can modify it, but if you toss the original list away you're effectively making it permentantly read only.

From the Thread Safety section of the collection:

> A ReadOnlyCollection can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

So if you don't touch the original list again and stop referencing it, you can ensure that multiple threads can read it without worry (so long as you don't do anything wacky with trying to modify it again).

Answer (score 3):

> In other words if the original list is guaranteed not be written to, is it safe for multiple threads to use .Where or foreach on the IEnumerable?

Yes it's only a problem if the list gets mutated.

But note than `IEnumerable<T>` can be cast back to a list and then modified.

But there is another alternative: wrap your list into a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and pass that around. If you now throw away the original list you basically created a new immutable list.

Comment: you are correct.  However the drawback of using ReadOnlyCollection is that there is no compile time warning for myList.Add() for example, where this is not an issue with IEnumerable.  Now I wonder if I take my original IList and do .AsReadOnly().AsEnumerable()?

Comment: @e36 AFAIK `ReadOnlyCollection` implements `Add` explicitly. So `myList.Add` wouldn't work. Only when `((IList<T>)myList).Add` works. That's enough typesafety for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using net framework 4.5 or greater, this could be a great soulution
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

(microsoft already implemented a thread safe enumerable)