# Autofac ThreadSafe Resolve by Metadata Property Name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Using Autofac Dependency injection I'm attempting to resolve a service inside of a parallel operation and keep it thread safe. I'm using the following example code below:

```
public class ThreadCreator
{
  private ILifetimeScope _parentScope;

  public ThreadCreator(ILifetimeScope parentScope)
  {
    this._parentScope = parentScope;
  }

  public void ThreadStart()
  {
    using (var threadLifetime = this._parentScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
      var thisThreadsInstance = threadLifetime.Resolve<MyThreadScopedComponent>();
    }
  }
}
```

My current (non thread safe code) looks like this:

```
    public class ReportService : IReportService
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> _reportGeneratorServices;

        public ReportService(IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> reportGeneratorServices)
        {
            _reportGeneratorServices = reportGeneratorServices;
        }

        public TestMethod(){
          //Not thread safe when called inside a Parallel.ForEach
          var reportServiceLazyLoad = _reportGeneratorServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name == myMetaDataName);
        }
     }
```

How can i resolve using metadata name property class in a thread safe manner? I can't figure out how utilize the `threadLifeTime` variable to resolve an instance of a service by `MetaData.Name` property filtering in a manner that is limited to the specific thread, basically converting the second block of code into the first block where its threadsafe.

Thank you!!

Comment: well for the example you showed (second snippet) you're already thread safe check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978726/ienumerablet-thread-safety

Unless you post more detailed question it would be hard to help

Answer (score 0):

You may substitute `IEnumerable` for `ConcurrentBag`, this will guarantees a thread safe execution into collection/array level. But if you want to propagate de execution of all scope with alias or named thread, the best alternative is put the code invoke execution into one [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-6.0). With [Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-6.0), you can define a name of thread and guarantees the thread safe control out of application domain, in other word, in operational system level